# Client-side switching accounts

Tags: svn, active-directory

On svn server we use active directory to authenticate users. however, users won't always be logged in to a machine on a company domain (customer sites, home computer, etc.)

However, instead of prompting for credentials (or even taking them in through command line --username and --password) it simply returns: "access to  is forbidden"

how can I have svn take in a different set of active directory credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an issue. When tried to access SVN from client, it asks credentials. On client side it is not tied to Windows login (I assume you use TortoiseSVN). Is this what you wanted to know? If not, please elaborate.

Comment: It does not ask for credentials.

Comment: Maybe it has already been saved. To clear cached authentication - Right-click in any folder -> TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> Saved data -> Authentication data -> Clear. Let me know if it works.

Comment: does the same from a fresh install.

Comment: no, ended up not needing to get it working this way, however, shouldn't --username at least pass a username?